# Python list's reference do not change in function

Tags: python, reference

Here are my test codes.

**Test 1**:

```
def set(object):
    object = [2,3]
a = [1,3]
set(a)
print a
```

The output is **[1,3]**

**Test 2**:

```
def set(object):
    object[0] = 2
a = [1,3]
set(a)
print a
```

The output is **[2,3]**

For **Test 2**, I can know it well, because `a` is a list, which transfer reference in python. So when call `set(object)`, `object` is a reference of `a`. Therefore `a` change into `[2,3]`.
But for **Test 1**, I have not knew it well. I think the answer is `[2,3]`, but the real answer is `[1,3]`. Can anyone tell me the two test case's differences?

Answer (score 0):

In the second test case, you are trying to mutate the existing list, so that will work.

But, in your first test, you are trying to assign a new list on variable `a`, but you are doing it inside function scope, rather you should return `object` and receive it in `a`.

```
>>> def set_value(a):
...     a=[2,3]
...     return a
...
>>> a=[1,3]
>>> a = set_value(a)
>>> a
[2, 3]
```

Comment: I would recommend against calling it `set`, even though that's the name the OP used.

Comment: Actually I just followed OP's naming, I am aware that it can conflict with set(). Updating.